# Django set data from db into field

Tags: django, webforms, django-views

I am trying to fill two `<input type="text">` fields with value from a database, with default django forms.

I tried to set it with query, but it gets value when it starts and won't take it from DB after values were changed id DB.

My forms looks like:

```
s_size = forms.IntegerField(initial=Sizes.objects.get(id=1).small)
m_size = forms.IntegerField(initial=Sizes.objects.get(id=1).medium)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a form for a django model? because `ModelForms` will take care of this sort of thing. Either way, can you show more of your form (like how you are initializing values from the DB)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.. thanks seri.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass in the initial data from the view, as described [in the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    s_size = forms.IntegerField(i)
    m_size = forms.IntegerField()
```

...

```
def my_view(request):
    s_size_value = Sizes.objects.get(id=1).small
    m_size_value = Sizes.objects.get(id=1).medium
    form = MyForm(initial={'s_size': s_size_value, 'm_size': m_size_value})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need recreate form class for each request.

```
def my_form_factory():
    class my_form(forms.Form):
        s_size = forms.IntegerField(initial=Sizes.objects.get(id=1).small)
        m_size = forms.IntegerField(initial=Sizes.objects.get(id=1).medium)
        ...
    return my_form()

def my_view(request):
    form=my_form_factory()
```

Other solution - update form fields in form's `__init__()` method through self.fields dictionary:

```
class my_form(forms.Form):
    __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(my_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['s_size']=forms.IntegerField(initial=Sizes.objects.get(id=1).small)
        self.fields['m_size']=forms.IntegerField(initial=Sizes.objects.get(id=1).medium)
```